# Prevent Alias From Converting Domain Name in Browser Address Field

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

I'm using Amazon Web Services. I've set up my domain name in Route 53, set up static website hosting in S3, and I've successfully mapped the domain name to the S3 bucket using a DNS ALIAS record set. So far so good.

When I fire up a browser and point it to www.example.com, I get served the index.html resource from my S3 bucket. Also good.

The problem I'm having is that when I do this, the address is converted in the browser address field from http://www.example.com to http://example.com.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com

The latter is the address of the S3 bucket, and technically that is the correct source. But, I want the address to stay the same. In other words, I don't want the URL www.example.com to be replaced with the S3 bucket URL in the browser address field.

Can I fix this with some additional DNS record sets or something?

Comment: DNS won't help you here. The "conversion" in the browser bar is due to a HTTP redirect, which is going to be related to your webserver configuration. I have no experience with S3 unfortunately.

Comment: Correct! Editing post with update.

Comment: Please post an answer as a true answer, not as an edit to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A helpful forum poster over on AWS helped me to figure it out. It is indeed not a DNS-related issue, but rather a webserver one. In this case, the webserver effectively being AWS S3. It was incorrectly set up with a redirect to (not surprisingly) route requests from the actual domain to the S3 bucket address. Actually I think that the user documentation was accurate but I made a mistake during the configuration.

Comment: redirecting often happens after authentication, so thats a good place to start looking